# Are cupboards safe in my house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know chests are safe, the items that I put there will stay forever. Is that also true for cupboards? Because I like to separate chests according to the item category.

Comment: I'm sure every container in your house is safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that all containers in your house are supposed to be safe, there should be no difference between cupboards, dressers or chests. I've been keeping my stuff for a long time now in all kinds of containers in my home, nothing has vanished so far.

There is also a loading screen tip saying

> Items can be safely stored in any container in your house.

<sub>I wasn't fast enough to get a screenshot of this loading screen</sub>

Comment: So... does this mean that if I store stuff in certain crates around town that I should be worried about items disappearing? That will change my gameplay... crap, now I'll have to move all my crap into a house... wait, I never bought the f*ing house... grrr... off to buy a house!